# job history webui-19888 in hadoop2.7.2 multinode shows noting after job has finished

Tags: java, maven, hadoop, hadoop-yarn, hadoop2

after I ran a job in hadoop2.7.2 with 2 slaves ,I can see a result in terminal, but in  master:19888/jobhistory is nothing.I uploaded the picture and my config files.
[job history webui 19888](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nJ56Z.png)

and here is my config files.
core.site.xml

```
<property>
    <name>fs.default.name</name>
    <value>hdfs://master:9000</value>    
</property>

   <property>
    <name>hadoop.tmp.dir</name>
    <value>/app/hadoop/tmp</value> 
</property>
```

hdfs.site.xml

```
<property>
<name>dfs.replication</name>
<value>2</value>
</property>

<property>
<name>dfs.name.dir</name>
<value>file:/usr/local/hadoop/hadoop_tmp/hdfs/namenode</value>
</property>

<property>
<name>dfs.data.dir</name>
<value>file:/usr/local/hadoop/hadoop_tmp/hdfs/datanode</value>
</property>
```

mapred.site.xml

```
<property>
    <name>mapred.job.tracker</name>
    <value>master:54311</value>    
</property>

<property>
    <name>mapred.framework.name</name>
    <value>yarn</value>
</property>

<property>
<name>mapred.jobhistory.address</name>
<value>master:10020</value>
</property>
```

yarn.site.xml

```
<property>
<name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>
<value>mapreduce_shuffle</value>
</property>


<property>
<name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services.mapreduce.shuffle.class</name>
<value>org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ShuffleHandler</value>
</property>

<property>
<name>yarn.resourcemanager.resource-tracker.address</name>
<value>master:8025</value>
</property>

<property>
<name>yarn.resourcemanager.scheduler.address</name>
<value>master:8035</value>
</property>

<property>
<name>yarn.resourcemanager.address</name>
<value>master:8050</value>
</property>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The property is `mapreduce.framework.name` in `mapred-site.xml`

```
<property>
    <name>mapreduce.framework.name</name>
    <value>yarn</value>
</property>
```

The current property `mapred.framework.name` is not valid and is not recognized. Thus, the jobs are being submitted in `local` mode. Locally run jobs are not tracked by jobhistoryserver.

Modify the property name and restart the services.

Comment: thanks,it worked.Do you know where I can see the container's feature such as cpu and ram for each task?

Comment: In ResourceManager UI. That would be in port `8088` by default.

Comment: in master:8088/cluster/app/application_1489002640363_0001, shows Total Resource Preempted:  <memory:0, vCores:0>
Total Number of Non-AM Containers Preempted:  0
Total Number of AM Containers Preempted:  0
Resource Preempted from Current Attempt:  <memory:0, vCores:0>
Number of Non-AM Containers Preempted from Current Attempt:  0
Aggregate Resource Allocation:  101448 MB-seconds, 62 vcore-seconds,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,it shows memory 0 and vcore 0,is that true?

Comment: whats that mean container were preempted?

Comment: [Preemption](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.3/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/CapacityScheduler.html#Capacity_Scheduler_container_preemption)

Comment: you mean that I should enable it in yarn.site.xml?

Comment: No, It is part of capacity scheduler. Unless you require preemption, it does not require modification. One container per task will be used, the memory specs of the container should be available in the UI itself. I believe you are looking at the Scheduler specs. You can check for Cluster Specs.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137591/discussion-between-mndn-and-franklinsijo).

Comment: I need to know each task are running on which container.I want to know the differences between containers for tasks.
what is this means"Unless you require preemption, it does not require modification"?what is modification?
sorry I am new in hadoop ,,,